# How do I calculate a sliding 3 month average based on the rolling sum of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table where I track conversions and the historic data is actual data which has been verified by an external source but I want to use those conversions to try to project the future values based on the previous 3 months worth of data. Below is a sample but in the real scenario I am projecting further into the future not just the 12 months on show.

My database is azure sql server, I've tried using various window functions as well as recursive cte but either way I couldn't get it to give me the desired outcome. I think its because I'm trying to do calculate the values based off calculated values.

Source data:

| CalendarYear | CalendarMonth | Conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | .25 |
| 2023 | 2 | .37 |
| 2023 | 3 | .17 |
| 2023 | 4 | .48 |
| 2023 | 5 | .21 |
| 2023 | 6 | .08 |
| 2023 | 7 | NULL |
| 2023 | 8 | NULL |
| 2023 | 9 | NULL |
| 2023 | 10 | NULL |
| 2023 | 11 | NULL |
| 2023 | 12 | NULL |

Expected data:

| CalendarYear | CalendarMonth | Conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | .25 |
| 2023 | 2 | .37 |
| 2023 | 3 | .17 |
| 2023 | 4 | .48 |
| 2023 | 5 | .21 |
| 2023 | 6 | .08 |
| 2023 | 7 | .257 |
| 2023 | 8 | .182 |
| 2023 | 9 | .173 |
| 2023 | 10 | .204 |
| 2023 | 11 | .186 |
| 2023 | 12 | .188 |

Below is one attempt of what I was trying to do, I was starting off with the first record in the data then I was trying to recursively join back onto the source data and if the conversion was null I was trying to do the avg() but it returns null in the database - I suspect because its averaging null rather than the sliding 3 months of previously calculated data. Within this I tried to left join back onto the cte but you can't reuse it multiple time - I also attempted something similar while trying to do a subquery back onto the main cte.

```
 ;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    CalendarYear,
    CalendarMonth,
    ConversionRate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth) AS rn
  FROM Data
), recursive_cte AS (
  SELECT
    cte.CalendarYear,
    cte.CalendarMonth,
    ConversionRate,
    cte.rn
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cte.CalendarYear,
    cte.CalendarMonth,
    CASE
  WHEN cte.ConversionRate IS NULL THEN
    CAST(avg(recursive_cte.ConversionRate) OVER (ORDER BY cte.[CalendarYear], cte.[CalendarMonth] ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS DECIMAL(5, 4))
  ELSE
    cte.ConversionRate
END AS ConversionRate,
    cte.rn
  FROM cte
  JOIN recursive_cte ON cte.rn = recursive_cte.rn + 1
)
SELECT
  CalendarYear,
  CalendarMonth,
  ConversionRate
FROM recursive_cte;
```

Comment: You have forgotton to include your existing attempt and explain the logic required.

Comment: I'm my guess is correct on where `0.182` comes from (`AVG(0.08,0.21,AVG(0.08,0.21,0.48))`) then you're going to need to use recursion.

Comment: @Stu I didn't forget, I just wasn't sure which was the correct direction to go so I didn't want to add something which might have been making people look in the wrong direction. I've added one example of what I have tried but I've been on this for awhile and I've got about 400 lines of commented out SQL with various attempts.

Comment: The logic explaination was "forgotten" in my opinion, @StephenErrington , as I'm **guessing** the logic for `Conversion` here.

Comment: I'm hoping to calculate the sliding 3 month average for each null value based on the previous 3 months which might also be calculated but it could also be real data if its the first 3 months from today

Comment: @ThomA Your guess is correct and the logic is based on a rolling calculation of AVG(0.08,0.21,AVG(0.08,0.21,0.48)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution, that unpivots your rows into columns, using `LAG`, and then uses an rCTE to recurse through the data. This, however, is fixed to 3, so doesn't scale.

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(2023,1,.25),
            (2023,2,.37),
            (2023,3,.17),
            (2023,4,.48),
            (2023,5,.21),
            (2023,6,.08),
            (2023,7,NULL),
            (2023,8,NULL),
            (2023,9,NULL),
            (2023,10,NULL),
            (2023,11,NULL),
            (2023,12,NULL))V(CalendarYear, CalendarMonth, Conversion);

GO

WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT CalendarYear,
           CalendarMonth,
           Conversion,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
rCTE AS(
    SELECT CalendarYear,
           CalendarMonth,
           CONVERT(decimal(3,3),COALESCE(Conversion,AVG(Conversion) OVER (ORDER BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))) AS Conversion,
           CONVERT(decimal(3,3),LAG(Conversion) OVER (ORDER BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth)) AS PriorConversion,
           CONVERT(decimal(3,3),LAG(Conversion,2) OVER (ORDER BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth)) AS PriorConversion2,
           RN,
           1 AS I
    FROM RNs
    WHERE Conversion IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RN.CalendarYear,
           RN.CalendarMonth,
           CONVERT(decimal(3,3),(r.Conversion + r.PriorConversion + r.PriorConversion2) / 3) AS Conversion,
           CONVERT(decimal(3,3),r.Conversion),
           CONVERT(decimal(3,3),r.PriorConversion),
           RN.RN,
           r.I +1
    FROM RNs RN 
         JOIN rCTE r ON RN.RN = r.RN + 1 AND RN.Conversion IS NULL)
SELECT CalendarYear,
       CalendarMonth,
       Conversion
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY I,
         RN;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works.. you honestly have no idea how long I've been on this for and I actually attempted something like this earlier today but I was left joining back onto the cte using RN-1 then RN-2 but I couldn't get it to fully work so thought I was going down the wrong solution and gave up.. Currently the requirement I have is for 3 months but I know that soon there will be 6/12 months.. Is there a way to make this more dynamic to allow a dynamic average range? If its too complicated I'd be happy with just creating 3 stored procedures which handle 3/6/12.